# SQLite database + Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, sqlite, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

im currently studying jquery mobile and ive been looking for tutorials on making a sqlite database on mobile app using jquery and html but ive been encountering are tutorials with phonegap on them.is it possible not to use phone gap.i dont want to use phone gap so im wondering if it is mandatory to use phone gap to make sqlite data base.and if you have any tutorials available please post it thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might helps you...

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

and

http://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/ .

Answer (score 2):

From within HTML5+jquery mobile applications you do not have access to the Android SQlite.
try webSQL.

Comment: what i want is to have a external text file where i can save data like username password data in autocomplete save in autocomplete is it feasible with websql?if it is can you show me how no idea on web sql